# How to send invoice as PDF after order

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, invoice, pdf

After the customer completed the checkout I would like to send him a custom invoice as email, not only the HTML version. I found pages about [custom PDFs](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/custom-pdf-templates/) but not how to add those PDFs to the order mail.

I found an [module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-pdf-invoice-layout.html) for this but it's not for current versions.

Comment: This will do: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-email-attachments.html

Comment: If you want to do that manually, why not use the "Print" button during viewing the order from the backend, it generates a PDF then you can send it per email.

Comment: Here is something that might be helpful: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-pdf-invoice-layout.html

Answer (score 1):

Fooman attachment will do the trick for you.
Also you can check and try [Easy PDF Invoice](http://www.easypdfinvoice.com/)